# Execute a batch of processes: asynchronous or continuous?

Tags: .net, asynchronous, continuous, external-process

The user now launched the "Convert all" function, it should run a seperate process for each of them items.

What's the recommeded way, convert them one after the other one by one, or launch a seperate conversion thread for each of the items letting all the processes work simultaneously?

My question is, maybe since there are too many progresses at a time, all of them work slower which might then be better converting them one by one? What is the most efficient approach?

Comment: The answer may depend on what this "convert all" function does.

Comment: @JohnSaunders, This function should be responsible that a certain process is started for each of the items (each item with a separate process).

Comment: How many processes are we talking about? Are we running on a multi-core processor or are we trying to throttle a windows 7 phone? How long is each process expected to run?

Comment: @Carth it's hard to predict if user will want to convert 200 files of 20MB each or 3 files of 1GB each or mixed. The average however should be each file 30-600MB about 10-50 files for a batch.

Comment: With that kind of variation I think you're going to want to go with a fixed worker thread pool so you can achieve the benefits of parallel processing without opening yourself up to an endless amount of slicing. Jason's answer is realistic. You're going to need to test and tweak to determine what's right for you. With data of this size and a presumably extended conversion period I think you'd likely want to set the expectation with your users of an asynchronous processing queue regardless.

Comment: @Carth, that's no doubt, that the conversion is made asynchronously updating user with progress on each progress + overall progress. The question is just if it's better not to run them parallely, or one after the other. I guess I will have to try making a queue of process (is there a so-called proper official way to do this?). Any related info will be very appreciated as well!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this is highly specific to the nature of the processing (it's highly dependent on what the bottlenecks are, what the shared resources are, etc.). Only you can answer the question by writing it both ways and using a profiler to measure the performance.

Comment: Which means both ways might be considerable. I wanna make sure I don't do anything wrong.

Answer (score 1):

It depends the work load of the conversion you are trying to achieve. You might want to take a more balanced approach by limiting your thread pool size. It takes some testing to see what's the best configuration.